# What can i do in this case? Setinterval within setinterval countdown timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need help or idea for use a countdown inside a setInterval.

heres my countdown timer on js (pretty obvious):

```
function startTimer(duration) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        document.getElementById('minuteDrag').innerText = minutes;
        document.getElementById('secondDrag').innerText = seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

When i call this function outside the second setinterval, that works pecfectly (as expected).
But when i tried to run this function in the code below, the function for time countdown gets bugged, i guess it's because the countdown timer is called within another setinterval.

Any ideas for a solution here? (i can't get out the "main setinterval").

```
var api = new Lolesports_API();

api.get_event_details('pt-BR', '105562529627228920')
.then(result_games => {         
        var game_id
        result_games.event.match.games.forEach(game => game_id = game.id)
        api.get_teams('pt-BR')
        .then(result_teams =>{
            var teams_dict = {}
            result_teams.teams.forEach(team => {teams_dict[team.id] = team.code})
            setInterval(function(){
                api.get_window(game_id, get_lastest_date())
                .then(result_window => {                
                    var last_frame = result_window.frames[result_window.frames.length - 1];
                    var game_state = last_frame.gameState;
                    startTimer(60*5)
                    if (game_state == 'in_game') {
                        document.getElementById("gameState").style.backgroundColor = '#33cc33';
                        stopwatch_game.start();
                    } else if (game_state == 'paused') {
                        document.getElementById("gameState").style.backgroundColor = '#66a3ff';
                        stopwatch_game.pause();
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("gameState").style.backgroundColor = '#ff8080';
                        stopwatch_game.pause();                  
                    }
                    //stopwatch_game.start();

                })
            }, 500)
        })
})
```

PS: this is not the full code, i remove a large part in order not to pollute the question.

Comment: Either stop the old timer before starting a new one, or don't start another timer if there's already a timer running.

Comment: A better idea is to use an unique setInterval loop  for everything and  switching inside for your differents code usage

Comment: I cant stop the setinterval with 0.5ms. how can i put the countdown time inside the second setinterval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're starting a new CountDown Interval every half second.

Why not return the value from the setInterval in startTimer so that it can be stopped as necessary by the outer loop?

e.g.

```
startTimer = (duration) => {
    let timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    return setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        document.getElementById('minuteDrag').innerText = minutes;
        document.getElementById('secondDrag').innerText = seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then in your main loop you can use `clearInterval` to stop the timer... or at least check if it exists:

```js
let foo = undefined;
if (foo === undefined) {
  foo = startTimer(60*5);
}
```

Comment: That works!! thankyou. I just dont get when you say "can use clearInterval", clearinterval ignore the main loop?